# Extending Magento's topLinks to Include Nested/Dropdown Child Menu's

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

We've extended the Magento class `Mage_Page_Block_Template_Links` using the method outlined by Sonassi [here](http://www.sonassi.com/knowledge-base/magento-kb/nested-xml-menus-using-addlink-in-magento/).

Editing the `_construct` function to include our custom template:-

```
protected function _construct()
{
    $this->setTemplate('page/template/links_nested.phtml');
}
```

Editing the function `addLink` to include `$childMenu` variable and allow this to be used in XML layout:-

```
public function addLink($label, $url = '', $title = '', $prepare = false, $urlParams = array(), $position = null, $liParams = null, $aParams = null, $beforeText = '', $afterText = '', $childMenu = false)
{
    if (is_null($label) || false === $label) {
        return $this;
    }

    $link = new Varien_Object(array(
        'label' => $label,
        'url' => ($prepare ? $this->getUrl($url, (is_array($urlParams) ? $urlParams : array())) : $url),
        'title' => $title,
        'li_params' => $this->_prepareParams($liParams),
        'a_params' => $this->_prepareParams($aParams),
        'before_text' => $beforeText,
        'after_text' => $afterText,
        'child_menu' => ($childMenu ? $this->getLayout()->getBlock($childMenu) : '')
    ));

    $this->_links[$this->_getNewPosition($position)] = $link;
    if (intval($position) > 0) {
        ksort($this->_links);
    }

    return $this;
}
```

Then we wish to include `<childMenu>` parameter in local.xml for an item in topLinks:-

```
<reference name="top.links">
    <action method="addLink" translate="label title before_text">
    <label>Account</label>
    <url />
    <title>Account</title>
    <prepare />
    <urlParams />
    <position>10</position>
    <liParams>id="account-dropdown"</liParams>
    <aParams />
    <before_text />
    <after_text />
    <childMenu>account-submenu</childMenu>
    </action>
</reference>
```

And then construct the childMenu as `account-submenu`:-

```
<reference name="top.links">
<block type="page/template_links" name="submenu" as="submenu">
    <action method="setName">
    <name>account-submenu</name>
</action>
<action method="addLink" translate="label title before_text">
    <label>Contact Us</label>
    <url />
    <title>Contact Us</title>
    <prepare />
    <urlParams />
    <position>110</position>
    <liParams />
    <before_text />
    <after_text />
</action>
</block>
</reference>
```

Then we've made a few modifications to the template file to render `childMenu` if declared:-

```
<?php $_links = $this->getLinks(); ?>
<?php if(count($_links)>0): ?>
<ul class="links nav"<?php if($this->getName()): ?> id="<?php echo $this->getName() ?>"<?php endif;?>>
    <?php foreach($_links as $count=>$_link): ?>
        <?php if ($_link instanceof Mage_Core_Block_Abstract):?>
            <?php echo $_link->toHtml() ?>
        <?php else: ?>
            <li<?php if($_link->getIsFirst()||$_link->getIsLast()||$count): ?> class="<?php if($_link->getIsFirst()): ?>first<?php endif; ?><?php if($_link->getIsLast()): ?> last<?php endif; ?> link-<?php echo $count ?>"<?php endif; ?> <?php echo $_link->getLiParams() ?>>
                <?php echo $_link->getBeforeText() ?><a href="<?php echo $_link->getUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $_link->getTitle() ?>" <?php echo $_link->getAParams() ?>><?php echo $_link->getLabel() ?></a><?php echo $_link->getAfterText() ?>
                <?php var_dump($_link->getChildMenu()); ?>
                <?php echo ($_link->getChildMenu()) ? $_link->getChildMenu()->toHtml() : ''; ?>
            </li>
        <?php endif;?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Everything is working as expected apart from the fact that `childMenu` doesn't render anything at all in the front end, so the 'My Account' top link contains no submenu.

Is there something incorrect with the call for `childMenu` in the template file ?

```
<?php echo ($_link->getChildMenu()) ? $_link->getChildMenu()->toHtml() : ''; ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the layout XML, you should define your submenu block (`<block>` node) before adding it to the top links (`<action method="addLink">` within `<reference name="top.links">`). As Magento treats the nodes as they come, he won't know that the block exists otherwise

Comment: This didn't appear to make any difference at all.

Comment: Even when directly using `<block type="page/template_links" name="account-submenu" as="submenu">` ? (as it is actually done in Sonassi example: `<childMenu>mymainmenu.sublinks</childMenu>` corresponds to `<block type="page/template_links" name="mymainmenu.sublinks" as="mymainmenuSubLinks">`)

Comment: Yes, even by using exactly the same as what the Sonassi article provides (we've tried countless variations and carried out a lot of debugging on this already), `<childMenu>` just returns false no matter what we try. It just isn't getting the block as defined in the XML.

Comment: Is the cache disabled or refreshed ?
If so, is your sub-menu block defined before the main menu in your layout ?

Comment: Cache is disabled in Magento. Browser cache is cleared. Reference `top.links` is defined in local.xml inside `<default>` and then directly after this, the block for the submenu defined. There is little else in this local.xml file (can send it to you if you wish to take a look)? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it would be interesting to be able to take a look at the layout part of your local.xml file, as the problem certainly has to do with the order of definitions and references

Comment: Great, thanks - [local.xml](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/8388505/Files/local.xml). From line 92. Thanks.

Comment: How did you rewrite the `Mage_Page_Block_Template_Links` class ? (knowing that in their tutorial Sonassi use a custom block instead of rewriting the `page/template_links` class and the corresponding base `top.links` block)

And anyway, could you try to move the block `<block type="page/template_links" name="mymainmenu.sublinks" as="mymainmenuSubLinks">[..]</block>` before the reference that adds it to `top.links` ?

Comment: Extending `Mage_Page_Block_Template_Links` like the article from Sonassi walks through doesn't even work. The class just wasn't extending. The only workaround I found was to copy the file Links.php into the replicated local pool applying the changes Sonassi provides in this file. All that we touched in Links.php was the functions that the Sonassi extension extended. [Here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/8388505/Files/Links.php). I can just paste all files in use to Dropbox if easier? I don't know where the Sonassi article gets `reference name="mymainmenu.links` from either.

Comment: Yes, the Sonassi example is actually incomplete and needs a few changes to get it working, but this is why it was quite confusing to find what was not working. So, putting the submenu block definition before it's added to the top links with the `reference` should definitely fix your problem.

Comment: That's it, you've done it. Ah super work, thank you very much. To clarify, keeping the block within `<default>` in `local.xml`, I moved the reference to block above the first instance of `top.links`. The block also uses `action method` `SetNameInLayout` too. Please update your answer and I can mark it as the answer. Thanks again for persevering with this one! :)

Comment: Could you please post the solution here? I have the same problem and I can't find a solution reading the comments here

Answer (score 0):

To anybody having any issues with this - I thought I'd post my solution.

I don't think it's too wise to copy the core Page/Block/Template/Links.php file from app/code/core to app/code/local and making the adjustments to that file (what happens if this Links.php file is updated in a future Magento update, you'd need to ensure your override complies with the new updated file from the core).

Anyways, the issue here is definitely that the instructions are missing a step - everything makes sense right to the point where they reference (out of nowhere) the block **"mymainmenu.links"** - this block doesn't exist anywhere, hence it won't work. And if you keep adding your links to the **"top.links"** block, Magento will just keep using the default block to display your links. So the obvious answer here is to create a new block.

In your layout file add the following block (I'm using local.xml) **app/design/frontend/(*package*)/(*theme*)/layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <layout version="0.1.0">
        <default>
            <reference name="header"> <!-- You could also use root here to give it a larger scale access -->
                <block type="templatelinks/page_template_links" name="mymainmenu.links" as="mymainmenuLinks">
                    <action method="setName">
                        <name>mymainmenu-links</name>
                    </action>

                    <action method="addLink" translate="label title">
                        ....
                    </action>
                </block>
            </reference>
        </default>
    </layout>
```

Setting the block type to **(*custom module name*)/(*block location*)** instantiates our custom module and and processes our actions through that.

You'll also have to remember to display your newly created (in this instance **mymainmenuLinks**) block in our template(s) - In most cases it'll be your **app/design/frontend/(*package*)/(*theme*)/template/page/html/header.phtml** file

Locate

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topLinks') ?>
```

And replace with your new block name

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('mymainmenuLinks') ?>
```